# Circular import in Flask using Blueprint

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

Want to make redirection of endpoints to differets controllers via blueprint, but it makes error circular import. Can't understand where is cyclicality.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\stein\PycharmProjects\techTasks\filmorate_*init*_.py", line 2, in 
from app import routes
File "C:\Users\stein\PycharmProjects\techTasks\filmorate\app\routes.py", line 2, in 
from filmorate.app.view.FilmController import FilmController
File "C:\Users\stein\PycharmProjects\techTasks\filmorate_*init*_.py", line 9, in 
app.register_blueprint(routes.app_blueprint_film)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'app.routes' has no attribute 'app_blueprint_film' (most likely due to a circular import)

code:

```
**__init__.py**

from flask import Flask
from app import routes


app = Flask(__name__)
app.json.ensure_ascii = False
app.register_blueprint(routes.app_blueprint_film)
app.register_blueprint(routes.app_blueprint_user)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080)



**app.routes.py**

from flask import Blueprint
from filmorate.app.view.FilmController import FilmController
from filmorate.app.view.UserController import UserController


app_blueprint_film = Blueprint('films', __name__)
FilmController.register(app_blueprint_film)

app_blueprint_user = Blueprint('users', __name__)
UserController.register(app_blueprint_user)

**app.view.FilmController.py**

from flask import request
from filmorate.model.Film import Film
from flask_classy import FlaskView, route
from filmorate.app.service.FilmService import FilmService


class FilmController(FlaskView):
    pass
```